# Is one allowed to split path integrals in the Feynman-Vernon Influence theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, propagator, open-quantum-systems

In QFT the propagator $J(t,t_0,x_f,x_i) = \langle x_f | U(t,t_0) | x_i \rangle$ fulfills the property
$$
J(t,t_0,x_f,x_i) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx' J(t,t',x_f,x')J(t',t_0,x',x_i)
$$ 
and can be expressed in terms of Feynman path integrals by
$$ J(t,t_0,x_f,x_i) = \int_{x_i}^{x_f}\mathcal{D}x e^{i\int_{t_0}^{t}dt'\mathcal{L}(x,\dot x)} $$
When dealing with open quantum systems one can determine the time evolution of the open system through the propagator $J_{\text{FV}}$ of the reduced density matrix in the Feynman-Vernon formalism
$$ J_{\text{FV}}(x_f,x_i,y_f,y_i,t,t_0) = \int_{x_i}^{x_f}\mathcal{D}x\int_{y_i}^{y_f}\mathcal{D}y e^{i\int_{t_0}^{t}dt'(\mathcal{L}(x,\dot x)-\mathcal{L}(y,¸\dot y))}\mathcal{F}(x,y) $$
with the influence functional $\mathcal{F}$, that carries the information about the environment.
Does the propagator $J_{\text{FV}}$ fulfill the same property as $J$, i.e. is it true that:
$$
J_{\text{FV}}(x_f,x_i,y_f,y_i,t,t_0) \\= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx'\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy' J_{\text{FV}}(x_f,x',y_f,y',t,t')J_{\text{FV}}(x',x_i,y',y_i,t',t_0)
$$

Comment: Quick comment : In general no. For example you can look at exact influence functional which can be obtained using model system of arbitrary system coupled bi-linearly to harmonic oscillator bath.